# Função para checar palíndromo

Tags: javascript, string, lógica

Eu tenho o desafio de escrever um código para checar se um texto é um palíndromo ou não. Ainda não terminei o código, no momento, está assim:

```
function checkPalindrome(str) {     
var direita = [];
for(var i = 0; i<str.length; i++){      
    direita.unshift(str.charAt(i)); 
    }
    console.log(direita);
var esquerda = [];
for (var j=str.length-1; j>=0; j--){
    esquerda.push(str.charAt(j));
}
    console.log(esquerda);
    };
```

Até aqui eu quis ver se eu poderia ler uma *string* normalmente e ao contrário. Jogaria as duas leituras em 1 vetor cada para depois, compará-los e dizer se é palíndromo ou não.Enfim, ocorre que, ao testarmos no console do Google Chrome ou outro, ele executa só `esquerda.push(str.charAt(j));` para os dois vetores, não lendo a expressão nos dois sentidos necessários. O que pode estar errado?

Um palíndromo é um texto que pode ser lido normalmente, ou invertido, que terá o mesmo significado. Exemplo: "reviver", "luz azul", "radar".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se a função é para checar, e tem isso até no nome, é altamente provável que ela deva retornar se é verdadeiro ou falso. E mesmo que não fosse isso, só se ela dissesses explicitamente que deve imprimir é que deveria fazê-lo.

Não entendi o que está tentando fazer nesse código, mas se for o que está descrito na pergunta é mais simples, é só ir verificando o primeiro com o último, o segundo com o penúltimo, e assim por diante até chegar no meio, por isso só precisa ir até a metade. Qualquer um par que fure a condição já garante que não é um palíndromo e nem precisa continuar, somente será um palíndromo se passar por todas sem falhar.

```js
function checkPalindrome(str) {     
    for(var i = 0; i < str.length / 2; i++) if (str[i] != str[str.length - i - 1]) return false;
    return true;
}
console.log(checkPalindrome("radar"));
console.log(checkPalindrome("reviver"));
console.log(checkPalindrome("palindromo"));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Palindrome.js).

A pergunta não deixa claro se deve aceitar frases, se for necessário teria que eliminar os espaços antes. Aí pode-se adicionar um passo anterior, que é menos eficiente, ou terá que fazer uma algoritmo mais complexo que vai ignorando o espaço, o que é significativamente mais complexo e nem sei se será tão mais eficiente assim.

Comment: Resolveu o meu problema e eu também aprendi mais. De fato, eu também não pensei se eu deveria considerar frases ou não. Lá na Code Signal também não ficou claro para mim. Muito obrigado! @Maniero

Answer (score 9):

Podes reverter a string e comparar assim: `str === str.split('').reverse().join('')`

```js
const testes = ["reviver", "luz azul", "radar", "manhã"];
const checkPalindrome = str => str === str.split('').reverse().join('');
const resultados = testes.map(checkPalindrome);
console.log(resultados);
// dá: true, false, true, false
```

Para ignorar espaços em branco podes fazer:

```js
const testes = ["reviver", "luz azul", "radar", "manhã"];
const ignoreSpaces = str => str.split(' ').join('');
const checkPalindrome = str => ignoreSpaces(str) === ignoreSpaces(str.split('').reverse().join(''));
const resultados = testes.map(checkPalindrome);
console.log(resultados);
// dá: true, true, true, false
```

Answer (score 2):

para que o palíndromo que comece com letras maiúsculas tb seja contado como true use:

```
function checkPalindrome(str) {
  return str.toLowerCase()==str.split('').reverse().join('').toLowerCase()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Divida a palavra em um array, salvando-a em uma variável.
2. Inverta o array.
3. Monte de novo.
4. Compare a string inicial com a reversa.

**0.52 ms**

```js
function checkPalindrome(str){
  let reversed = str.split("").reverse().join("")
  return str === reversed
}


console.log(checkPalindrome("reviver"));

console.log(checkPalindrome("luz azul"));

console.log(checkPalindrome("manhã"));
```

Você pode simplificar ainda mais usando ES6:

```js
function checkPalindrome(str){
  let reversed = [...str].reverse().join("")
  return str === reversed
}

 console.log(checkPalindrome("reviver"));

console.log(checkPalindrome("luz azul"));

console.log(checkPalindrome("manhã"));
```

**0.30 ms**

```js
function checkPalindrome(str){
  let le = str.length;
  if (le === 0 || le === 1) {
    return true;
  }
  if (str[0] === str[le - 1]) {
    return checkPalindrome(str.slice(1, le - 1) );
  }  
  return false;
};

    console.log(checkPalindrome("reviver"));

    console.log(checkPalindrome("luz azul"));

    console.log(checkPalindrome("manhã"));
```

**0.20 ms**

Nesta solução, iremos inverter a string, desta vez usando um loop for para verificar se as letras são exatamente as mesmas em ambos os lados.

1. Declare uma variável com o comprimento da string.
2. Declare um loop for, usando metade do comprimento da string como ponto de referência.
3. Verifique se cada letra é igual ao seu equivalente do outro lado (medido com índice - 1).

```js
function checkPalindrome(str) {
 let l = str.length;
 for (let i = 0; i < l/2; i++) {
  if (str[i] !== str[l - 1 - i]) {
   return false;
  }
 }
 return true;
}

        console.log(checkPalindrome("reviver"));

        console.log(checkPalindrome("luz azul"));

        console.log(checkPalindrome("manhã"));
```

[Fonte](https://medium.com/better-programming/algorithms-101-palindromes-8a06ea97af86)

[Veja mais soluções no StackOverflow em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813369/palindrome-check-in-javascript/25091111#25091111)

Answer (score 1):

melhorando o codigo de uma resposta dada. Ela não pegava o caso da palavra começar sendo iguais, ela ja retornava true, mas nao necessariamente era um palíndromo!

```
const checkPalindrome = (str) => {
    let result = ''
    for (var i = 0; i<str.length / 2; i++ ) {
        if (str[i] !== str[str.length -i -1]) return result = false
        result = true
    }
    return result
}

console.log(checkPalindrome("palindromo"));
console.log(checkPalindrome("radar"));
console.log(checkPalindrome("reviver"));
console.log(checkPalindrome("antgretdna"));
```