# Exercício Palindromo JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de entender esse código na forma mais simplista possível.

```
var palindromo = "";

for(var i = palavra.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   palindromo += palavra[i]
}

if (palavra == palindromo) {
   return "SIM, SOU UM PALÍNDROMO"
} else {
   return "INFELIZMENTE, NÃO SOU UM PALÍNDROMO"
}
```

Sei que no primeiro for ele faz a verificação de forma invertida.

Mas quero entender o processo dessa parte:

```
palindromo += palavra[i]
```

Como ficaria a palavra OVO e a palavra SIM.

Seria:

Posição da palavra SIM

0 = S
1 = I
2 = M

3 - 1 = posição 2 que é a letra 'M'

```
palindromo += palavra[i]
```

"" = "" + SIM [M] - Seria isso? Como fica essa parte?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Função para checar palíndromo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/315456/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-para-checar-pal%c3%adndromo)

Comment: `palavra[i]` pega o caractere que está na posição `i` da string `palavra`, então quando `i` vale `2`, a expressão `palavra[i]` resulta em uma string contendo apenas a letra "M". E como o operador `+`, quando aplicado a strings, faz a concatenação, então a expressão `palindromo += palavra[i]` está adicionando o caractere no final da string `palindromo`. Portanto, o *loop* adiciona a última letra, depois a penúltima e assim por diante, até a primeira. No final a string `palindromo` contém os caracteres da `palavra` na ordem inversa, e se ambos forem iguais, é porque a string é um palíndromo.

Comment: Eu coloquei como resposta o que eu pensei.

Comment: Na verdade, o índice não é "M" ou "I", e sim `2` ou `1`, etc.  Então quando `i` vale `2`, a expressão `palavra[i]` é "traduzida" como `palavra[2]`, que é o caractere que está na posição `2` (ou seja, a letra "M"). E no terceiro passo, "MI" + "S" resulta em "MIS", e não "SMI" (cada novo caractere é adiiconado no final)

Comment: Mas a ideia é isso mesmo o que coloquei na resposta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você inicializa a variável "palindromo" como uma string vazia -> ""

```
var palindromo = "";
```

Faça um **loop** pelo tamanho da variável "palavra", nesse caso, vamos supor que: var palavra = "SIM"

```
for(var i = palavra.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
   palindromo += palavra[i]
}
```

Esse loop é pouquinho diferente, você começa com "`var i = palavra.length - 1;`"
"SIM" tem 3 letras, menos 1 = 2, logo `var i = 2`
Enquanto i for maior ou igual a 0, você irá decrementar o valor dele, ou seja, i = i - 1

Dentro do loop você executa isso: `palindromo += palavra[i]`
Na primeira iteração do loop seu i é igual a 2 e palíndromo igual a ""
Uma string no javascript pode ser tratada como uma Array, então quando você executa `palavra[i]` nesse caso `palavra[2]` você está selecionando a letra "M" que é a posição [2] de "SIM". E incrementa no final da variável "palindromo"

1. Na primeira interação -> i = 2, palindromo = "" e termina como "M"
2. Na segunda interação -> i = 1, palindromo = "M" e termina como "MI"
3. Na terceira interação -> i = 0, palindromo = "MI" e termina como "MIS"

Agora você simplesmente compara se a palavra original é igual ao palíndromo gerado, por exemplo `"SIM" == "MIS" = false` e `"OVO" == "OVO" = true`

```
if (palavra == palindromo) {
   return "SIM, SOU UM PALÍNDROMO"
} else {
   return "INFELIZMENTE, NÃO SOU UM PALÍNDROMO"
}
```

Comment: i = 0 né? No item 3. que você colocou.

Comment: Entendi, mas quero saber da forma que eu coloquei na resposta como ficaria, entendeu, vou colocar outra resposta que talvez seja o que você quer dizer.

Comment: Eu vou colocar mais dúvidas iguais a essa, eu gosto de entender o código certinho. Até mais.